# javascript api restful name functions, good practices

Tags: javascript

I need advise about the name for the functions inside a service that calls restful api (i know there is not actually standards); Let's see how is used in two ways on the angular.io site:

1. on the tutorial , http section :
   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

save ()
delete ()
put ()
post ()

2. on developper guide for http, for the hero.services.ts :

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#http-
client

getHeroes ()
addHero ()

search() is in another file: search.services.ts

3. On another tutorial  on the web:
   http://offering.solutions/articles/angular/consuming-a-rest-api-with-angular-2-http-service-in-typescript/

GetAll
GetSingle
Add
Update 
Delete

(I don't like is not camelCase ) but names is clear

my question is:

a. I like when the functions's name have no the object's name , like addHero (), could i use simple add () on the service and component is consumed ?

b. search service can be joined on the same file service?

c. there is another advise for the api restful?

Comment: Go with what works for you, keeping in mind its better to be explicit, its good to be able to figure out what a functions purpose is from its name

Comment: thanks @Craicerjack